# Text overlapping container and onto 2nd page in vertical mobile view

Tags: css, css-position, containers

So on the "about" page, I have everything in a container. Right now on a big screen, when i click "click to slide panel right" area, a block of text slides right.  When I resize to less than 720px the panel disappears and the text block should disappear too, however it is showing up in smaller screen on the right and overlaps the other pages.

a) how do i contain this text block
b) I think I know how to figure out how to move the text below the image after that, so when viewed in mobile the picture is center of the screen(which i have already implemented). The block of text then appears without any animation added (just appears static) below the image in the container area.
Been trying to solve this for a few hours now, but I have a feeling its my positioning? What am I doing wrong in my code? Thank you!

[freecodecamp personal portfolio project](http://codepen.io/max77p/pen/JGQNVg)

```css
.secondpage{
  background-color:pink;
  height:57em;
}

/*.title{
  padding-top:.5em;
}*/

.picture{        
  padding-top:10em;
  padding-bottom:0em;
}

.img-circle{
  width:20em;
  height:20em;
  border:.2em solid;
  border-radius:50%;
}


/*start of toggle panel design*/
/***********************************************************************************************************************/
@media screen and (max-width: 720px) {
  .img-circle{
  margin-left:auto;
  margin-right:auto;
    margin-top:-8em;  
  }
 
 
  }


#flip{
position:absolute;
  transform:rotate(-90deg);
  margin-left:6em;
  margin-top:-6.1em;
  border:.1em solid;
}

.title{
  margin-left:22em; 
  margin-top:-24em;
  
}


.contthird1{
  background-color:red;
  height:100%;
}
.title p{
 border:.1em solid;
    color: rgba(0,0,0,0.9);
  width:100%;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 720px){
  .title>p{
    border-style:none;
  }
}

.title a:hover{ 
  text-decoration:none;
  color:blue;
  font-weight:bold;
}/*for self taught link*/
```

Comment: Hello, it's very hard to understand what it is you want us to help. Please clarify. What do you want to do with the text? Hide it *or* push it below?

Comment: I want to push it below the picture, but right now when i try the text is going outside of the container and overlapping onto the "portfolio" page. Having trouble fixing this. @Av Avt

Comment: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/VawmZr is this what you want?

Comment: @AvAvt omg yes, i see that you added   ".title {margin: 0; }".  Could you please help me understand what was actually happening that something so simple fixed it?

Comment: Ok, I'll make an answer then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fix is simply to add

```
@media screen and (max-width: 720px) {
  .title {
    margin: 0;
  }
}
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/VawmZr

It is because in the wide version, the title is aligned to the top right side not by floating, but with a negative margin:

```
.title{
  margin-left:22em; 
  margin-top:-24em;

}
```

When this negative margin is gone, it will go back to where it should be as a block element.